# How do you check the type of variable when using arrays?

Tags: c++, templates, variables, vector

I'm trying to create a header that uses templates and vectors that will sort an array in ascending order either numerically or alphabetically based on it's contents. However, I need to check the type o variable before organizing it,since the array can be either an int array or string array or so on. I know how to organize it, but how do I check the variable type to determine which temp to assign it to? Here's what I have:

```
template <class T>

void SortableVector<T>::sort()
{

int temp1 = 0;


double temp2 = 0;

float temp3 = 0;

string temp4 = "";  

if (this->operator[](0) //is an int
{

temp1 = this->operator[](0);
}

else if (this->operator[](0) //is a double
{

temp2 = this->operator[](0);
}

else if( this->operator[](0) //is a float
{

temp3 = this->operator[](0);
}

else if (this->operator[](0) //is a string
{

temp4 = this->operator[](0);
}

for (int count = 0; count < this->size(); count++)
{
}

}
```

Comment: Isn't `T` your type ? You could specialize your function.

Comment: The whole point of writing a template is so that you don't need to know the exact type. What would you write differently if T is int vs string?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use function specialization here:

```
template<typename T>
class SortableVector {
private:
    T* _internal;
    /* ... */
public:
    void sort();
};

template<typename T>
void SortableVector<T>::sort() {
    /* sort a general unknown type */
}

template<>
void SortableVector<bool>::sort() {
    /* sort bools */
}

template<>
void SortableVector<int>::sort() {
    /* sort ints */
}

/* etc. */
```